# Are there any different words for stewed meat and a stew with meat?

Tags: single-word-requests

These are two different ways of cooking meat. I know I can stew meat, i.e. boil it with little amount of water and then eat it without any water. Or I can make a soup that is also called "stew" but it has water and other ingridients. Those two different methods use the same words "stew". Is there any way to say "stewed meat" so that it is completely clear it's not a soup?

Comment: I think "stewed meat" works fine. We tend not to use stewed to refer to the soup called stew.

Comment: @JohnClifford , The problem is I was trying to search for recipes related to the stewed meat but everythigng I find is making soups. I thought there might be another way to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **casseroles**,

> a kind of stew or side dish that is cooked slowly in an oven.

beef **stews**

> a dish of meat and vegetables cooked slowly in liquid in a closed dish or pan.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stew) says

> **Stews** are similar to soups, and in some cases there may not be a clear
>   distinction between the two. Generally, **stews have less liquid than
>   soups, are much thicker and require longer cooking over low heat.**
>   While soups are almost always served in a bowl, stews may be thick
>   enough to be served on a plate with the gravy as a sauce over the
>   solid ingredients.

**slow cooker** beef stews

> a large electric pot used for cooking food, especially stews, very slowly.

and **braised** beef.

> fry (food) lightly and then stew it slowly in a closed container

**Beef** refers to the flesh of cows, bull or ox.
**Meat** refers to any animal flesh

Soup that is made from diced or minced/ground meat is not called *stew*, it is beef soup see: [Home-Style Vegetable Beef Soup](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/26427/home-style-vegetable-beef-soup/?internalSource=staff%20pick&referringId=445&referringContentType=recipe%20hub)

Comment: But I heard stewed beef and braised beef are different. Are they the same thing?

Comment: @German  Both cooking methods are very similar, the main difference being that stews tend to also contain potatoes and other cubed vegetables. See Google images for [braised beef](https://www.google.it/search?q=braised+beef&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThq-Ls6_LAhVEAA8KHZ0MCw4Q_AUIBygB&biw=1366&bih=677)